# Attempting to sync slicers: run time error 438

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to sync two slicers from two different data sources. I will use the first slicer to change the view of multiple charts. The field from the different data sources is the same with the same values in it. I am new to VBA so just learning this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    'Declaring variables
    Dim sc1 As SlicerCache
    Dim sc2 As SlicerCache
    Dim SI1 As SlicerItem

    'These names come from Slicer Settings dialog box
    Set sc1 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Customer_Region1")
    Set sc2 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Customer_Region2")

    'make the macro faster
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Clearing filters to mirror sc1
    sc2.ClearManualFilter

    'Getting error here
    For Each SI1 In sc1.SlicerItems
    sc2.SlicerItems(SI1.Customer_Region).Selected = SI1.Selected 
    Next SI1

    'make the macro faster
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting the error at: sc2.SlicerItems(SI1.Customer_Region).Selected = SI1.Selected

Comment: Looks like the `SlicerItem` class doesn't define a `Customer_Region` property?

Comment: Sorry still fairly new to this, so what would I have to do to add that?

Comment: You don't own that class, it's part of the Excel type library. Maybe you meant to get `sc2.SlicerItems(SI1.Name)`? I don't know your data, so it's hard to tell. But error 438 means you're making a late-bound member call that VBA can't resolve at run-time.

Comment: I updated it to:For Each SI1 In sc1.SlicerItems
    sc2.SlicerItems(SI1.Name).Selected = SI1.Selected
Next SI1  .................Getting a run time error 5 : invalid procedure call or argument error now on that same line